# Is there any exposed APIs by Zalenium to view the live execution

Tags: zalenium

Does Zalenium has any exposed APIs which could be used to view the live execution of the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Zalenium is build on top of Selenium Grid. So you can see the live video execution at [here](http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/live?refresh=20)